# Spring XD and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-xd

Is it possible to develop custom module, which uses existing Spring Boot Application with JPA / Hibernate, REST Services? What's the proper way to package and deploy such custom module in Spring XD.

Comment: This is much easier with Spring Cloud Dataflow. Instead of using XD, I am now using SCDF.